# How to get the access token of all the users who have signed up on my web app using one tap signin

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-my-business-api

I am trying to get the access token of the users when someone given the access to use gmb web application.i am able to console when i am testing but i am unable to retrieve the accounts the users who have given the access to my platform and i also wants to know how cann i retrieve the user.
Here i am using google one tap signin

```
<div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id="xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      data-callback="handleResponse"
    ></div>
```

and here is the handleResponse

```
function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        const config = {
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage",
          client_id:
            "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        };
        gapi.auth2.authorize(config, function (response) {
          var requestOptions = {
            method: "GET",
            redirect: "follow",
          };
          console.log(response.access_token);
          fetch(
            `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token=${response.access_token}`,
            requestOptions
          )
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((result) => console.log(result))
            .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
        });
      }
```

and i am using this code for getting all the accounts

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```